# Sprite not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I have a sprite defined and it isn't appearing when I run the app. Here is my code and some images to help figure out the error:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var SingleplayerButton: SKSpriteNode! = nil

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        SingleplayerButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Unknown")
        SingleplayerButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        SingleplayerButton.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if SingleplayerButton.containsPoint(location) {



            }

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget `addChild` to your scene

Comment: To help you out a bit more, you can also use the "sprite.parent == nil" property to check if a sprite has already been added to the scene. This is to make sure other objects or the same sprites are added on the scene already. This can be used when automatically adding enemies, etc.